# Debugging Open WebOS

Tags: debugging, webos

I build open webOS in Ubuntu machine and able to see in Emulator.

Im in the process of optimizing some components(services, kernel). so I need guidance from experts for a **debugger** which gives me call stack as well as functions execution time from top most layer.

For example, If I click contact application, what are all the things happening upto kernel.

When I googled for this, **Palm Inspector**, **weinre** , **phonegap** were suggested(which is not suitable for me). I request you to guide me in this regards.

Comment: Did you try "make webos-image-devel"?

Comment: @Sergei, As of now Im using perf, systemtap for profiling.

Comment: I've seen simple and informative gui in DDMS of Android ADK plugin for Eclipse. Tell me if such profiling would be what you need. If yes, then we could think about how to use it. If not, please clearify what other information you need (kernel execution times, probably, something else).